# "schnell auf der Straße stehen" meaning

Tags: meaning, phrase, colloquial

What does it mean "schnell auf der Straße stehen" in this sentence "Durch Verletzung oder Vereinsinsolvenz können auch junge Spieler schnell auf der Straße stehen."?

Comment: When I read the title (i.e. had no context) I thought about a really expensive and fast car standing in a traffic jam ;-)

Comment: Joachim: mee to.

Comment: I thought about Berlin humor/irony, but without cars. Here in Berlin, we don't need cars for standing on the streets. :)

Comment: Mich erinnerte es direkt an "... drinnen saßen stehend Leute, schweigend ins Gespräch vertieft ..."

Answer (score 18, accepted):

„Auf der Straße stehen“ in this context means to be unemployed; the sentence says that there's a high risk for young (soccer?) players to lose their job in case of injuries or if their club becomes insolvent.